# Loading Base64 String into Python Image Library

Tags: python, django, image, base64, python-imaging-library

I'm sending images as base64 string through ajax to django. In my django view I need to resize the image and save it in the file system.

Here is a base64 string(simplified):

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRg-it-keeps-going-for-few-more-lines=
```

I tried to open this in PIL using the below python code:

```
img = cStringIO.StringIO(request.POST['file'].decode('base64'))
image = Image.open(img)
return HttpResponse(image, content_type='image/jpeg')
```

I'm trying to display the uploaded image back, but firefox complains that `'The image cannot be displayed because it contains error'`

I couldn't figure out my mistake.

**SOLUTION:**

```
pic = cStringIO.StringIO()

image_string = cStringIO.StringIO(base64.b64decode(request.POST['file']))

image = Image.open(image_string)

image.save(pic, image.format, quality = 100)

pic.seek(0)

return HttpResponse(pic, content_type='image/jpeg')
```

Comment: Have you tried with: `base64.b64decode(request.POST['file'])`?

Comment: Yes, I'm getting   

cannot identify image file

Comment: Have you tried withing an interpreter sessions? Just encode the file, decoded it later and see if it works?

Comment: Yes, tried. There is no issue with decoding the string.

Comment: Try somewhere to print exactly what you're getting with: request.POST['file'] and see if it's the same string that works in your interactive session.

Comment: They are exactly the same...

Comment: Dont' save files in a database. http://stackoverflow.com/a/41235395/267540

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

Saving the opened PIL image to a file-like object solves the issue.

```
pic = cStringIO.StringIO()
image_string = cStringIO.StringIO(base64.b64decode(request.POST['file']))
image = Image.open(image_string)
image.save(pic, image.format, quality = 100)
pic.seek(0)
return HttpResponse(pic, content_type='image/jpeg')
```

Comment: This solution seems wrong. Using PIL, one forces the image to be saved as a valid JPEG, which it is not (see my answer below)? So it's probably slightly corrupted but one cannot notice it.

Answer (score 4):

The beginning of the POSTed string (`data:image/jpeg;base64,`) is a header and should be removed before the decoding.
The image is corrupted otherwise.

```
photo = request.POST['photo'].partition('base64,')[2]
image_data = b64decode(photo)
someobject.photo.save('user.jpg', ContentFile(image_data), save=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class PhotoHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        rawbase64 = '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'
        pic = cStringIO.StringIO()
        image_string = cStringIO.StringIO(base64.b64decode(rawbase64))
        image = Image.open(image_string)
        image.save(pic, image.format, quality = 100)
        pic.seek(0)
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'image/png'
        self.response.write(pic.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Praveen's solution for python2, but I find out python3 version would be:

```
import io
import base64
pic = io.BytesIO()
image_string = io.BytesIO(base64.b64decode(base64_str))
image = Image.open(image_string)
image.save(pic, image.format, quality=100)
pic.seek(0)
return HttpResponse(pic, content_type='image/jpeg')
```

Please notice `data:image/jpeg;base64,` part is not actually the base64 string so if your base64 string contains that you should remove it:

```
base64_str = base64_uri[23:]
```