# Strange IOError when opening base64 string in PIL

Tags: python, base64, python-imaging-library, ioerror

I tried encoding an image and decoding the same in python shell. The first time I open the decoded base64 string in PIL there is no error, if I repeat the Image.open() command I'm getting *IOError: cannot identify image file.*

```
>>> with open("/home/home/Desktop/gatherify/1.jpg", "rb") as image_file:
...     encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())
>>> image_string = cStringIO.StringIO(base64.b64decode(encoded_string))
>>> img = Image.open(image_string)
>>> img
<PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=576x353 at 0xA21F20C>
>>> img.show() <-- Image opened without any errors. 
>>> img = Image.open(image_string)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1980, in open
    raise IOError("cannot identify image file")
IOError: cannot identify image file
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create your `image_string`, you're creating a fake file-like object backed by a string. When you call `Image.open`, it *reads* this fake file, moving the file pointer to the end of the file. Attempting to use `Image.open` on it again just gives you an EOF.

You need to either re-create your `StringIO` object, or `seek()` to the beginning of the stream.

Comment: FYI, `Image.open` does not read the entire file (does not move the file pointer to the end of the file). It only reads the file header. See [Image.open](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm#tag-`Image.open`).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19908975/loading-base64-string-into-python-image-library
see if you can solve this issue, it's related to this question

Comment: I wasn't aware of that @falsetru, thank you. Makes sense to lazily load it, especially if you are working on large images (think 1GB+ NASA images)

Comment: Sorry, added incorrect link in the previous comment. See [`Image.open`](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm#tag-Image.open).

Answer (score 1):

`image_string` is file-like object. File-like object has file position.

Once the file is read, the position is advanced.

Any subsequent is occurred at that position unless you explicitly position it using [`seek`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek) method.

So if you want to reopen the file:

```
...
image_string.seek(0) # reset file position to the beginning of the file.
img = Image.open(image_string)
```