# PIL.Image.open() gives IOError: cannot identify image file

Tags: python, stream, python-imaging-library, stringio

I'm trying to save a jpg image from a Flask app form. The following code works fine:

```
blob = request.files[canvas_key]
blob.stream.seek(0)
data = blob.stream.read()
string_io = cStringIO.StringIO(data)
```

string_io has type `<cStringIO.StringI object at 0x10bf2bf10>`.

Yet when I try: `Image.open(string_io)`, I get this error: `IOError: cannot identify image file`.

Using `stream.seek(0)` seems to solve this problem for [other people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19910845/strange-ioerror-when-opening-base64-string-in-pil), but in my case it hasn't.

Comment: Does the stream have a HTTP header, or is it really a JPEG?  Does it have the string 'JFIF' in the first dozen bytes?

Comment: This is the `string_io` prefix: 'RIFF\xa2_\x00\x00WEBPVP8 ', which makes sense, because I'm getting the image from 'image/webp`, and "In 2010 Google introduced the WebP picture format, which uses RIFF as a container". This is the specific line of javascript that creates the image: `var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/webp');`

Comment: I don't think `WebP` even existed when PIL was last updated.

Comment: to build on @Marks' comment -- switch to the Pillow library.  It's a fork of PIL that's being updated, and supports WebP -- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.0.0

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Mark, I changed the image type I capture from WebP to PNG.