# How to serialize a image into str and deserialize it as image?

Tags: python, serialization, encoding, character-encoding, byte

I need to send an jpg image over network via `json`. I tried to convert the data into `str` via `base64`, as below:

```
  from PIL import Image
from tinydb import TinyDB, Query
import base64
import io
from pdb import set_trace as bp

# note: with 'encoding' in name, it is always a bytes obj

in_jpg_encoding = None

# open some randome image
with open('rkt2.jpg', 'rb') as f:
    # The file content is a jpeg encoded bytes object
    in_jpg_encoding = f.read()


# output is a bytes object    
in_b64_encoding = base64.b64encode(in_jpg_encoding)

# interpret above bytes as str, because json value need to be string
in_str = in_b64_encoding.decode(encoding='utf-8')
# in_str = str(in_b64_encoding)  # alternative way of above statement


# simulates a transmission, e.g. sending the image data over internet using json 
out_str = in_str


# strip-off the utf-8 interpretation to restore it as a base64 encoding
out_utf8_encoding = out_str.encode(encoding='utf-8')
# out_utf8_encoding = out_str.encode() # same way of writing above statement


# strip off the base64 encoding to restore it as its original jpeg encoded conent
# note: output is still a bytes obj due to b64 decoding
out_b64_decoding = base64.b64decode(out_utf8_encoding)

out_jpg_encoding = out_b64_decoding



# ---- verification stage
out_jpg_file = io.BytesIO(out_jpg_encoding)
out_jpg_image = Image.open(out_jpg_file)
out_jpg_image.show()
```

But I got error at the deserialization stage, saying the cannot identify the image as file:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "3_test_img.py", line 38, in <module>
    out_jpg_image = Image.open(out_jpg_file)
  File "/home/gaopeng/Envs/venv_celeb_parser/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2687, in open
    % (filename if filename else fp))
OSError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7f6f823c6b48>
```

Did I missed something?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31077366/pil-cannot-identify-image-file-for-io-bytesio-object) may solve your problem.

Comment: @Mr.cysl I tried `seek(0)` but still no result. I will try to save to file instead

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PIL cannot identify image file for io.BytesIO object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31077366/pil-cannot-identify-image-file-for-io-bytesio-object)