# http post byte convert to image file [cannot identify image file]

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, python-3.5

I'm having a Unity function writen in C# to allow users to upload customized images. The image is sent as byte[] in string format.
I have a simple flask backend server to save the images. However, when I worked with `io.BytesIO` and `Image.open()` functions, it shows `cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7f5599f43308>`
Here is my code:

```
@app.route("/post_file",methods=['GET','POST'])
def post_file():
    data = request.form.to_dict()
    json_byte = data['jsonbytes'] # posting a json byte[] and image byte[] with multi-form
    image_byte = data['imagebytes'] # a byte[] in string type
    image_byte = data['imagebytes'].encode() # byte[] type
    imageBytesIO=io.BytesIO(image_byte)
    imageBytesIO.seek(0)
    image = Image.open(imageBytesIO).convert('RGBA')
```

The code breaks at the last line.

```
 File "/home/iedl/editor/editor_app/app.py", line 37, in post_file
  image = Image.open(imageBytesIO).convert('RGBA')
  File "/home/iedl/editor/editor_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2818, in open
    raise IOError("cannot identify image file %r" % (filename if filename else fp))
OSError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7f5599f43308>
```

Comment: Please show the first 20 bytes of `image_byte`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PIL cannot identify image file for io.BytesIO object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31077366/pil-cannot-identify-image-file-for-io-bytesio-object)

Comment: @MarkSetchell it prints out messy code... `�PNG���IHDR����` something like this

Comment: I don't use JSON much, but I think I thought that it maybe probably possibly can't store null bytes... which may occur in PNG/JPEG or other binary image formats. Most people seem to base64 encode images in JSON. I may be completely wrong here... someone can kindly correct me if so. It will make it a bit slower and 30% bigger, mind you.