# Python error: PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x1144e9860>

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-imaging-library

I have the following script that prints the src path and sizes of all images on a specified url:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from PIL import Image
import requests

url="https://example.com/"

session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get(url)

b  = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(b.text, "lxml")

images = soup.find_all('img')

for img in images:
    if img.has_attr('src') :
        imgsize = Image.open(requests.get(img['src'], stream=True).raw)
        print(img['src'], imgsize.size)
```

It works fine for some url's but for others i get the following error:

**PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x10782e900>**

Is there a way to overcome this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having your specific url, I can't go and see why that's happening. But you can put in there a `try/except` so your script doesn't crash and will continue onto the next img

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from PIL import Image
import requests

url="https://example.com/"

session = requests.Session()
r = session.get(url)

b  = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(b.text, "lxml")

images = soup.find_all('img')

for img in images:
    if img.has_attr('src') :
        try:
            img_link = img['src']
            if img_link.startswith('data:image'):
                img_link = img['data-src']
            imgsize = Image.open(requests.get(img_link, stream=True).raw)
            print(img_link, imgsize.size)
        
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

Comment: Thanks. SVG images error too:No connection adapters were found for "data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,<svg xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg' viewBox%3D'0 0 980 735'%2F>". Is there a fix for this?

Comment: can you share the url you are using?

Comment: Yes its scanlite dot co dot uk (no www.)

Comment: Ah ok. Yup, those errors are pecouse there are svg. PIL does not support svg file [(read here)](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/handbook/image-file-formats.html). You'll need to use a different package for those

Comment: But there was a small adjustment needed on some others. I updated the code