# NameError: name 'data' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x

I copied the answer to this stack overflow quesiton [Decoding base64 from POST to use in PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26070547/decoding-base64-from-post-to-use-in-pil) 
ie:

```
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
import base64

data['img'] = '''R0lGODlhDwAPAKECAAAAzMzM/////wAAACwAAAAADwAPAAACIISPeQHsrZ5ModrLlN48CXF8m2iQ3YmmKqVlRtW4MLwWACH+H09wdGltaXplZCBieSBVbGVhZCBTbWFydFNhdmVyIQAAOw==''' 

im = Image.open(BytesIO(base64.b64decode(data)))
```

and ran it in my text editor and keeps saying data is undefined but I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `['img']`

```
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
import base64

data = '''R0lGODlhDwAPAKECAAAAzMzM/////wAAACwAAAAADwAPAAACIISPeQHsrZ5ModrLlN48CXF8m2iQ3YmmKqVlRtW4MLwWACH+H09wdGltaXplZCBieSBVbGVhZCBTbWFydFNhdmVyIQAAOw==''' 

im = Image.open(BytesIO(base64.b64decode(data)))
```

Comment: this worked! do you know how I then get the url to check the image?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what url are you talking about

Comment: so the data is the src of an image from google, but I want to be able to open that image? like view it in a browser.

Comment: Ok, you can go [here](https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter) and paste the content of data, without the first three `'''` and the last three `'''`.

Comment: hum it doesn't work, I think my full question entails a much longer post

Answer (score 0):

Just add `data = dict()` before the `data['img'] = ...`. `data` need to be define as a dict before you can access the dict key with the bracket operator.