# Django - Save base64 image from template to static

Tags: python, django, base64

I was wondering if it's possible to save an generated image from my template to the MEDIA_URL?
My image is generated in base64, I would like to give it a name and save it as png or jpeg to the MEDIA_URL

```
<img id="canvasImg" style="display:none;" src="data:image/png;base64,iVB...">
```

My image is generated using the [html2canvas](https://www.google.pt/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/&ei=lCVsU7DfEIuI7Abxu4BQ&usg=AFQjCNHHQirmNIY64Q0HCPckm3YHMxgTrA&sig2=IUay1bxyCYkcaVpAcAjAyQ&bvm=bv.66330100,d.ZGU) script. I then use this function to transform the canvas into an image:

```
function canvas2img(){
      html2canvas(document.getElementById("bg"), {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {      
          canvas.setAttribute("id", "canvas");
          var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png', 1.0);
          document.getElementById('canvasImg').src = dataURL;  
        }
      })
   };
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide a bit more info? How and where is your image generated?

Comment: Edited my question with more info.

Answer (score 2):

I won't post the full code here just some guidance, everything from StackOverflow:

First you need to send your base64 image to django using AJAX: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13198699/263989

Then get the base64 in an AJAX function:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
def get_bas64(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        # process the image
        return HttpResponse('')
```

To convert the base64 string to an image using PIL https://stackoverflow.com/a/19911883/263989

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply but I having trouble sending the base64 image to django. Can you plase explain me how to do it?

Comment: I'm getting `The view userdata.views.get_base64 didn't return an HttpResponse object.`

Comment: Yeah, you need to return an HTTPResponse, I edited the answer

Comment: Ok but I can't seem to send an AJAX request to my view, it always returns "Not Ajax" `@login_required
@csrf_exempt
def get_base64(request):
    if request.is_ajax():        
        pic = cStringIO.StringIO()
        image_string = cStringIO.StringIO(base64.b64decode(request.POST['file']))
        image = Image.open(image_string)
        image.save(pic, image.format, quality = 100)
        pic.seek(0)
        return HttpResponse(pic, content_type='image/jpeg')
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Not AJAX")`

Comment: I have created images upload like as facebook and amazon! Thanks for solutions!