# pytesseract on base64 string python

Tags: python, python-2.7, base64, python-imaging-library, tesseract

I have a whole bunch of image strings in base64 format for png images.  They are phone numbers (see http://www.trulia.com/profile/gerald-drexler-broker-neillsville-wi-10703037/overview for my working example, using the src tag from the number).  I would like to run them through pytesseract to extract the numbers.

I took some guidance from the answers here: [Loading Base64 String into Python Image Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19908975/loading-base64-string-into-python-image-library)

I tried several formulations, and I can't seem to figure out how to load the string correctly into PIL to run pytesseract on it.  Here's an example of an attempt:

```
from PIL import Image
import base64
import pytesseract
import cStringIO

imgstring = 'data: image/png;base64,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'
imgstring = imgstring.split('base64,')[-1].strip()
pic = cStringIO.StringIO()
image_string = cStringIO.StringIO(base64.b64decode(imgstring))
image = Image.open(image_string)
image.save('pic.png', image.format, quality = 100)
picture = Image.open('pic.png', mode='r')
picture.load()
picture.seek(0)

print pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(picture))
```

It seems to me that I must be going about this the hard way, but even after saving, loading, etc., I still get an `AttributeError: read`

What's the most efficient way to load these into memory for pytesseract to chew them up?  I haven't even gotten to the tesseract stage, and I have no idea how fast or slow it is, but I have millions of these to process.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jeff\Desktop\QS2\tess.py", line 16, in <module>
    print pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(picture))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2223, in open
    prefix = fp.read(16)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 605, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: read
```

Comment: Could you give us the full traceback? I currently have no idea what is causing the attribute error.

Comment: Traceback added.  Is that to say that this code works for you?  I've heard that PIL has issues in its Windows installations, would be interesting if that's the issue, here.

Comment: Isn't `picture` already an PIL.Image object? The argument to Image.open() is meant to be a file object or string. Perhaps change line 16 to `print pytesseract.image_to_string(picture)`.

Comment: I tried that first - in that one I get `WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified` - full traceback is too long.  The advantage of saving the file and opening it is that I can be sure that the file exists and looks fine.  The pic.png file is indeed a phone number png in the correct directory.

Comment: Pytesseract writes a temporary image to disk before calling tesseract-ocr in [pytesseract.py](https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract/blob/master/src/pytesseract.py#L128). If efficiency is an issue, you may have more luck with something like https://code.google.com/p/python-tesseract/ which claims not to write any temporary files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PNG transparency seems to be causing issues. Overlaying on a white background fixes the issue.

```
from PIL import Image
import base64
import pytesseract
import cStringIO

imgstring = 'data: image/png;base64,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'
imgstring = imgstring.split('base64,')[-1].strip()
pic = cStringIO.StringIO()
image_string = cStringIO.StringIO(base64.b64decode(imgstring))
image = Image.open(image_string)

# Overlay on white background, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/7911663/1703216
bg = Image.new("RGB", image.size, (255,255,255))
bg.paste(image,image)

print pytesseract.image_to_string(bg)

# Save the image passed to pytesseract for debugging purposes
bg.save('pic.png')
```

Comment: Pasting this exactly, I still get `WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified`

Comment: I tested it on Ubuntu. I'd recommend testing that the basic usage examples for [tesseract-ocr](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/ReadMe#Running_Tesseract) and [pyteseract](https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract/blob/master/README.md) work first. Pytesseract is just a thin wrapper around tesseract-ocr, so won't work without tesseract-ocr.

Comment: I failed to properly add the tesseract-ocr program file to the system's path variable.

Answer (score 3):

Issue for Python 3.*

```
from PIL import Image
import base64
import pytesseract
import io

imgstring = 'data: image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGcAAAAVCAYAAABbq/AzAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAADiUlEQVRoge3YTWgeVRQG4IcQJJQSQihBNIQiXYUSpJSgIF1IkSKllCJFQggutBQRQRfFH3RTRFwVERdBRHcuREVEupASRIP4C7VoFSmWSq2gtRGjNm21Ls79+k0mM3cmLrpxXhjm++aec973/sy55w4dOnTo0KFDhw4FLOIe3IWrmWtbwWcfLuDhinj7avzvTjyLDXp24F2cxx84gQMVdgfxHVbwFe5tqaEObXxynDCAQ/g2af+8hjM3ftcwIzoPQ5iouObEQG1INvP4PvlVBT+IYxVxhlJ7Vad6GMICHsQkNqWO/I7Zgt1s6twejGEvfhMLrI2GKjT5NHHCs6l/dyTtM8nnzkL/msbvGhbFTOdwDIfT7514GyN4ryb403glE+8JvN/AWcY8Xi/8P45HK+J+0FJDFZp8mjgHxRu1o2TzkH62aDN+YFS8tlMZQdP4S6yCMhZqgr8oVlAdtuFvDGdsyngHL6Xfw0L31pq4Qy00VCHn04bzlmSzsWQznmw2lJ7XjZ8BbMclfJ0R/CRexS8ZmzJGcb/+nnFcrJ6B1P4lroiJb8I4nhGD8FzhGZwu2Z5OHJtbaFiv7jacvTG6qWSzKdmMZbjX4D78kGnfisvYUtNeN/PDYr8Yxo2iCDiH5ws2ZxN/HY7ob8insKvQtj09Hyz5DOkXLm00rEd3G04iZR3Vn8xpkdKuWjtptW+O1HAyI/Y1vJFpzwYvYUakx17nTjb4Dor0MIH9YgPtpZxJ1emjl6YnGzTMWF2NzbTQ3ZZzRKTfc6KIOSoKiMu4oeRbO36DWK4g62GLGJTbM8LXg2/EKtuIpXRfzthfSe3LOJPub+EpkUr+ERNXTMkT6X6mQcObuLnw/NcWuttyLuGBUoxZkcovZXhWYQA/6efDMh7Hh/ikbcAGTCe+Jf38++M6/Iur7k98ZnWqk/5/oX7SexouJu7edbGF7v/KOYBH8HKGoxJjqqu1cVES5g5s1L+Wh3GbyNvjYm+5oH+QnEq8oxW+t4rSfkqkiDHsFmltvmC3R2zcu5LdbnHm2N9SQxWafJo4iYwwIhbTtCiXF1S/AI3bwqfWnnNeEAepJuRK6VOi4vlZnGmKK+4QPq6JuVmcZ86KBXI+2R6wtoNz4iS+Ik7txYFv0lCFNj45TuJguqL/ZeMxa/eaHhonZ07/C8H1wonE26EFPhKfSK4H9ia+Dh06dOjw/8G/sXcmUir28IcAAAAASUVORK5CYII='
imgstring = imgstring.split('base64,')[-1].strip()
pic = io.StringIO()
image_string = io.BytesIO(base64.b64decode(imgstring))
image = Image.open(image_string)

# Overlay on white background, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/7911663/1703216
bg = Image.new("RGB", image.size, (255,255,255))
bg.paste(image,image)

print(pytesseract.image_to_string(bg))

# Save the image passed to pytesseract for debugging purposes
bg.save('pic.png')
```