# $_FILES method doesnt import my image into db

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have created a Registration form in html, and with php i want the data to be stored in my database which i created for this one.

All the other things worked great, except the image doesn't show in phpMyAdmin.

This is the html form which i created:

```
 <tr>
    <td >Customer Image:</td>
    <td><input type="file" name="c_imag" required /></td>
</tr>
```

And this is the php code:

```
<?php
$c_imag = $_FILES['c_imag']['name'];
$c_imag_tmp = $_FILES['c_imag']['tmp_name'];
move_uploaded_file($c_imag_tmp,"customer/images/$c_imag");
?>
```

Unfortunately doesn't work, and dont know why, so im new in this field, and waiting for answer.

Comment: Where do you write anything to a database?  You're storing the image file on the file system, have you checked for it *there*?

Comment: Get some tutorial how to upload image on server and save to database. Its not the way you are doing it.

Comment: *"and waiting for answer."* - based on what? surely not what you posted.

Comment: you should use `mysqli` to connect to db.  :D

Comment: I've connected to database using this method:
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","mytable");

works good for all the others data I write into the HTML form (I mean the Name:...; Email:....; etc). Only the image doesnt work?!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Slowness found when base 64 image select and encode from database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41228496/slowness-found-when-base-64-image-select-and-encode-from-database)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me please check your folder path if this not works.
$c_imag = $_FILES['c_imag']['name'];
$c_imag_tmp = $_FILES['c_imag']['tmp_name'];

$path = 'customer/images/' . $c_imag;
move_uploaded_file($c_imag_tmp, $path);