# LOAD_FILE is loading NULL into BLOB

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu-14.04

I have a PHP application that I built that will store drivers into a BLOB.  However, the power went out the other day and the MySQL database wouldn't load so I had to remove MySQL-server and reinstall it (but I preserved all of the databases in /var/lib/mysql).  I give you this background because using LOAD_FILE to load these driver files into a BLOB worked before the power outage.  Since the reinstall of MySQL that has changed.

In the original setup I remember having this same problem and it had to do with 3 things.  First, I had to give the FILE Global Privilege, that the file needed to be on the actual server (which it is), and that the AppArmor MySQL profile needed to be disabled.  When I reinstalled MySQL-server on this Ubuntu 14.04 machine I had to disable the MySQL AppArmor Profile.  I then went a step further and just removed AppArmor because I'm tired of dealing with it.  However, LOAD_FILE is still loading NULL into the blob.  Not sure what I need to try from here?  Anybody have experience with this and want to help me double-check something I'm missing?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file

Comment: I'm not sure the link above helps.  I've tried everything stated in the documentation.  This PHP application is obviously owned by 'www-data:www-data' and the file that is created has these same ownership rights with -rw-r--r--.  This wasn't a problem before and changing the rights don't seem to make a difference.  That is the only thing I see that could've helped from the link above.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41228496/slowness-found-when-base-64-image-select-and-encode-from-database/41235395#41235395

Comment: Did you not see the part about the `max_allowed_packet` and `secure_file_priv` settings? Come on, it's only two paragraphs that you have to read. That section of the documentation is the canonical, official and complete reference for what you need to do to make `LOAD_FILE` work as you expect. So I don't understand why you think it doesn't "help".

Comment: @e4c5: That's not generally bad advice, but it's quite one-sided. It fails to mention any of the downsides of hiving off parts of your data to another location. It means you can no longer simply backup/restore your DB with a single tool, it means HA becomes more complex to implement, it potentially has integrity/transactional problems, etc etc.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit it's debatable whether the file itself should be considered part of the database. Having he files in the DB would actually make the backups a lot harder not easier.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, condescending remarks don't help.  I read the two paragraphs but needed more information.  I found it elsewhere and provided the answer below.

Comment: @user2643864: What was "condescending", except for what you said just now? The answer you give is exactly the requirement mentioned in the first paragraph of the documentation I kindly looked up for you and linked you to, which you claimed to have read and _"tried everything stated in the documentation"_, but apparently you didn't after all! Now I wish I hadn't tried to help. Glad you solved your problem. Good night.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So it seems from my previous MySQL version (that was damaged during the power outage) and the new version that I installed after the power outage (mySQL version 5.5.53) that the 'secure_file_priv' is now set to '/var/lib/mysql-files' by default, which prevents loading files from different locations.  TO FIX, I added secure_file_priv = "" to the [mysqld] section of the /etc/mysql/my.cnf and restarted MySQL.

The following documents clearly point out the issues step by step.  Much better than the vague MySQL documentation.

http://pastebin.com/Dvsdxh9Y
https://superuser.com/questions/1088512/how-to-disable-secure-file-priv-mysql-ubuntu

Comment: It's not "vague"; this requirement is clearly explained in the first paragraph of description for `LOAD_FILE`.