# ASP File Upload not submitting data to MySql database

Tags: mysql, asp.net, file-upload

I have an *ASP .NET Web Form* application to upload files to a *MySql 5.5* table.

When I click the submit button the query is executed but in the table only the Identity column gets a value.

The columns for the file attributes  i.e FileName(varchar (50)) , ContentType(varchar (50))
 and Content (medium blob)  are blank. All other controls e.g textboxes execute insert operations from the application except the `Asp:FileUpload` control.

My code is as below:

```
Protected Sub UploadFile()
        Dim filename As String = Path.GetFileName(fuCollateral.PostedFile.FileName)
        Dim contentType As String = fuCollateral.PostedFile.ContentType
        Dim iFileLen As Integer
        Dim byteFileData As Byte()
        Dim uploadedFile As HttpPostedFile = fuCollateral.PostedFile
        If fuCollateral.HasFile Then
            uploadedFile = fuCollateral.PostedFile
            iFileLen = uploadedFile.ContentLength
            ReDim byteFileData(iFileLen)
            uploadedFile.InputStream.Read(byteFileData, 0, iFileLen)

            Using fs As Stream = fuCollateral.PostedFile.InputStream
                Using br As New BinaryReader(fs)
                    Dim bytes As Byte() = br.ReadBytes(DirectCast(fs.Length, Long))
                    Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("constr").ConnectionString
                    Using con As New MySqlConnection(constr)
                        Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO imagefiles(FileName, ContentType, Content) VALUES (@FileName, @ContentType, @Content)"
                        Using cmd As New MySqlCommand(query)
                            cmd.Connection = con
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@FileName", filename))
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@ContentType", contentType))
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@Content", bytes))
                            con.Open()
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                            con.Close()
                        End Using
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
        End If
    End Sub
```

The code of the button click event:

```
Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click

  UploadFile()

End Sub
```

Screenshot of table after clicking submit:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/paEeU.png)

Comment: Are you sure your variables are set correctly at the time of cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()?

Comment: Dont' save files in a database. http://stackoverflow.com/a/41235395/267540