# swift 3 mysql json data parsing to UIImage

Tags: mysql, node.js, swift3

[image: This is the stuff returned by my nodejs request]i am storing images on mysql db as a medium blob, i am sending web request from ios device to nodejs server which fetches images from mysql and sends them back to the ios device in the response, i am having trouble parsing the data send back from the nodejs server. What i need to accomplish is transform the data that is sent back into UIImages so i can use them in my ios app. Also i know its not ideal to store images in database but thats what im doing. Any help is appretiated.

```
let task = session.dataTask(with: request)
    { data, response, error in


        if error != nil
        {
            print("error in web request")
        }
        else
        {
            DispatchQueue.main.async
            {

                    self.parseWebPhotos(stuff: data) //stoer results in class member

                    /*need to dispatch this to main queue since this is in closure, so needs to update ui so needs to
                     run on the main thread*/
                    self.getPhotosFinished()
            }


        }


    }//completion handler end

  func parseWebPhotos(stuff: Data?)
{


    if stuff != nil
    {

        if let dataAsAny: NSArray = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: stuff!, options: .mutableContainers) as! NSArray//checks that parsing didnt return error
        {
            let dic = dataAsAny[0] as! [String: AnyObject] //dictionary of all the pictures

            let pic0 = dic["pic0"] as! [String: AnyObject] //dictionary of pic0

            let data = pic0["data"] as! NSArray





            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("foo"), object: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Dont' save files in a database. http://stackoverflow.com/a/41235395/267540 and If I have understood your question corretly you are saving them has JSON????

Comment: I saved the files from the Mysql workbench ui, the datatype used to store them was medium blob

Comment: you don't save files into the workbench you save them into the server.