# upload image to mysql using jsp,servlets

Tags: mysql, jsp, servlets

using this code for uploading image to mysql

```
        Part filePart = request.getPart("photo");
    if (filePart != null) {
        // prints out some information for debugging
        System.out.println(filePart.getName());
        System.out.println(filePart.getSize());
        System.out.println(filePart.getContentType());
      // obtains input stream of the upload file
        inputStream = filePart.getInputStream();
    }
```

compiling giving an error

```
The method getPart(String) is undefined for the type HttpServletRequest
```

How to solve this ?

Comment: Dont' save files in a database. http://stackoverflow.com/a/41235395/267540

Comment: then ??? how to do

Comment: can u suggest ?

Comment: If you read that answer it's all there

Comment: ok i will check .thanq