# Upload file from browser to database

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, phpmyadmin

I'm working with phpMyAdmin to manage my database.

I have a table that stores a list of information about each user. In my website each user logs in and uploads a file to his account.

I know how to create an upload area using PHP and storing the uploaded file in a specified folder. But I don't know how to store the file in the database and link each user to the file he uploaded.

I want each user to be able to view their file every time they log into the website

Comment: Dont' save files in a database. http://stackoverflow.com/a/41235395/267540

Comment: *"I know how to create an upload area using php and storing the uploaded file in a specified folder."* - @e4c5 I'm pretty sure they're not wanting to store images "in" their database. The question is about *"But I don't know how to store the file in the database and link each user to the file he uploaded."* They probably meant "filename".

Comment: @user2950439 Can we get some clarification on this; do you want to store the binary file or the "filename"? Two different animals here.

Comment: Long story short: save the file in a folder, create a constant with the path to the image folder, so only your application will know it for security reasons, save only the name of the file to the database in a specific table, in that table you'll be able to link user id and any other information you want.

Comment: Ok you're not responding. You either left the question only to return at a later date or expecting a magic answer, which I might add won't happen, least not from me. Voted to close as being too broad. Try something then come back when you have difficulties with something. Or, take it up with the answers that have been given to you below, good luck.

Comment: I posted the question because I don't know the proper way. Long story short, I just want to know how to link each file to it's user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have only to save the path of the file inside your server, for example:

Table **users**:

```
Id     Name     ProfilePicture
1      John     /images/1/profilePic.png
```

The number 1 in the route represents the id of the user, that will make a folder for each user in your database.

That's one of the most simple ways to "store" images in your database.

Hope it helps!

Comment: How does the database create a folder for each user?

Comment: The database isn't creating that file for you, you will have to implement some server side logic with for example PHP or NodeJS.

Answer (score 0):

You need create a folder in htdocs/yourproject/ 
And storage all files if you need and in the database send the path dinamic to references to a file or the files