# Django UnicodeDecodeError "utf-8 can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0" while sending base64 encoded string

Tags: python, django, encoding, utf-8, base64

I am sending **base64** encoded string with this JavaScript code:

```
decodeURIComponent(escape(window.btoa(body.profile_image)))
```

In the back-end, I am using **Base64ImageField** from [drf-extra-fields](https://github.com/Hipo/drf-extra-fields)

```
from drf_extra_fields.fields import Base64ImageField


class StudentProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserInfoSerializer()
    clazz = ClassSerializer()
    profile_image = Base64ImageField(use_url=True)


    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ('user', 'clazz', 'profile_image', 'info')
        depth = 1


    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        user_data = validated_data.get('user', {})
        username = user_data.get('username', '')

        if User.objects.exclude(pk=instance.user.pk).filter(username=username):
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                'Student with this username already exists.'
            )

        instance.user.__dict__.update(**user_data)
        instance.user.save()

        instance.__dict__.update(**validated_data)
        instance.save()

        return instance
```

And when I send an image from the client, it throws **Error 500: Internal Server Error** with the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 217, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 215, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 109, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/response.py", line 72, in rendered_content
    ret = renderer.render(self.data, accepted_media_type, context)
    separators=separators
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 103, in render
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 237, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/json/encoder.py", line 256, in iterencode
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/json/encoder.py", line 198, in encode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/utils/encoders.py", line 54, in default
    return obj.decode('utf-8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

As long as I've read - I need to encode my image to **base64** and then the **Base64ImageField** cares about decoding it. The real surprise is that the image *is updated*, but the error is still thrown, which is really strange.
I tried some other encodings, but it still throws **Error 500**.

Comment: Does that field save images as Base64 text in a database? if so don't use it Dont' save files in a database at all. http://stackoverflow.com/a/41235395/267540

Comment: Your REST response handler is failing to decode data to UTF-8, probably the image. Perhaps you need to teach the serialiser how to return the image as Base64 data instead? (No idea how to do what with whatever Django extension you are using).