# How to create table column Field Multiple File Attachment in Php

Tags: php, mysql

I have Form  using php. in this Form i have Field .Select Main Category,subcategory,Description,Subject, last one attachment Field. how to create attachment column store multiple attachment  like picture and video  what ever we upload its store database

already i created Post category table following fields

```
Main category  varchar(50),

Sub category  varchar(50),

SubjectName varchar(50),

Description varchar(50),
```

last field Attachement how to create column Field to store database  multiple attachment

Comment: why you don't upload the file to the server and after the upload save the path of the file on your database?

Comment: Your table is wrong. Its better to store the media in a seperate table with a linked field containing the id of the shown table

Comment: OK @Super DJ i will  save separate  table

Comment: Dont' save files in a database. http://stackoverflow.com/a/41235395/267540

Comment: @e4c5 no way to store attachment file database  .please help me