# PHP output image instead of string

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Im a complete novice when it comes to PHP so apologies in advance.

I'm trying to query my table and return all the data in a table, I have the below working only it returns the last column as the longtext string and I'd like to use that as an image source so it returns an image, does that make sense?

```
try {
 $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
 $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
 $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `o18-reg`");
 $stmt->execute();

 $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

 foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt->fetchAll())) as $k=>$v) {
     echo $v;
 }
}
```

Comment: Dont' save files in a database. http://stackoverflow.com/a/41235395/267540

Comment: What is the string? The image as base64? the path to the file?

Comment: its base 64 @KhorneHoly yes

Comment: @Liam Ray's answer was faster and covers everything needed, just note that you need to use `base64_decode()` on the string before you're echoing it out.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, I d like to advise you should not place the image itself into database. You d better keep the Image URL or Absolute path in your file system into Database table.

Also please make sure you set correct `header` info when to `echo` the image data.
Without right `header`, it will be printed as string on client ends.

So if the image is jpeg, you can add header code before you use `echo` to print the image like following: (Also do not forget to do `base64_decode` if you have encoded image data using `base64`)

```
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
echo base64_decode($my_image);
```

If it is png, then you can use following:

```
header("Content-type: image/png");
echo base64_decode($my_image);
```

Comment: Note: since the string is base64, you need to use `base64_decode()` to turn the base64 back to the image