# Path syntax for LOAD_FILE using WAMP server

Tags: mysql, sql, database, command-line, blob

I am using a local database and I am trying to insert a image into a Photo VARBINARY(20000) column.

What is the path I have to use to LOAD_FILE?

```
INSERT INTO ImageTable(PHOTO) VALUES(LOAD_FILE('E:/wamp64/bin/mysql/mysql5.7.14/data/test.jpg'));
```

Is what I am using. This enter NULL into the table. MySQL is also under this path. Does the path have to be relative to something? I am using the command line.

Comment: Dont' save files in a database. http://stackoverflow.com/a/41235395/267540

Comment: do you get an error that the file was found or not? If not, then MySQL interprets the file correctly, then you have to look at the file contents.

Comment: i tried loading a file that is non-existent and it doesnt give any error anyways. @e4c5: I have the string too that I can `data:image/jpeg;base64` but it is too long to insert using the command line. Any tips on that?

Comment: read that answer closely

Comment: Ok so basically the answer tells me not to do it. But it is sort of a requirement for the app I m working on. I need to insert either the image or the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually if you're using image, Varchar is not the right type. You should use BLOB instead. This should cover it:

`INSERT INTO ImageTable(PHOTO) VALUES(1,LOAD_FILE('E:/wamp64/bin/mysql/mysql5.7.14/data/test.jpg'));`

Search further for **BLOB** and **LONG** **BLOB** to use images.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. It is of type VARBINARY(20000), not VARCHAR. :( I corrected it in the main post.

Comment: Anyway the code i wrote should help. I had the same problem once, only that I was using varchar to find the image path. Intead, BLOB will load the image on the link you insert. :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I am working on an existing database and am not supposed to change the column types. But using the absolute path is correct or, this is not a pathing issue?

Comment: Not a pathing issue. If the absolute path leads to an image, should work.

Answer (score 0):

I disabled --secure-file-priv and it worked. But unsure whether that was the problem because the error message for taht was not shown.