# ORA-01465: invalid hex number in python django

Tags: python, django, oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to upload multiple files in oracle 11g database using python django.

Here's my view

```
for filecol in request.FILES.getlist('file'):
    filename = filecol.name
    filetype = filecol.content_type
    fileblob = filecol.read()

FileRecord.objects.create(O_FILE_ID=oID, FILE_NAME=filename, FILE_TYPE=filetype, 
    FILE_BLOB=fileblob, DATE_UPLOADED=datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0))
```

Then I received this error message

```
return self.cursor.execute(query, self._param_generator(params))
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: ORA-01465: invalid hex number
```

Here in my models.py

```
class FileRecord(models.Model):
    O_FILE_ID = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(11)], blank=True, null=True)
    FILE_NAME = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    FILE_TYPE = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    FILE_BLOB = models.FileField()
    DATE_UPLOADED = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table= 'FILE_RECORD'

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.O_FILE_ID)
```

Sample data: `filename=Koala.jpg, filetype=image/jpeg, fileblob=''`

I'm planning to insert `base64` encoding in fileblob if possible.

Comment: Can you show us data in each variable ? (filename, filetype, fileblob)

Comment: can you show the definition of your FileRecord model?

Comment: Dont' save files in a database. http://stackoverflow.com/a/41235395/267540

Comment: I edited my question. tnx!