# ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value when uploading blob

Tags: python, django, oracle, oracle11g

I want to save blob to my database(oracle 11g) using python django. The output is ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert i
nto a LONG column

Here's my view

```
for filecol in request.FILES.getlist('file'):
    filename = filecol.name
    filetype = filecol.content_type
    fileblob = filecol.read()



FileRecord.objects.create(O_FILE_ID=oID, FILE_NAME=filename, FILE_TYPE=filetype, 
    FILE_BLOB=fileblob, DATE_UPLOADED=datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0))
```

I tried to encode it to base64, but same result

Comment: Show us the table structure/data type of the column where are trying to save the blob.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ORA-01465: invalid hex number in python django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41545110/ora-01465-invalid-hex-number-in-python-django)