# Output value from BLOB/binary-column from database

Tags: php, mysql, binary, blob

i've a field in a database which is saved as binary data. I just want to put out the data, that is in that field.

I used the following code but get no output. What's going wrong?

```
 $pdo = new PDO('sqldata);


$sql = 'SELECT name, datei FROM download WHERE id = 9';
$blob = 'SELECT CONVERT(datei USING utf8) FROM download WHERE id = 9';

    foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) { //for testing that the db-query works
        echo $row['name'] . $row['datei'].'<br>';
    } 

    foreach ($pdo->query($blob) as $row1) {
        echo $row1['datei'].'<br>';
    }
```

Comment: check the colors in this code, see where it go's wrong..

Comment: using convert on binary data? Seems odd. Field-type of datei?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41235395/267540

Comment: type of datei is binary. and I can't change the saving of the data. I got this database and have to look whats in the field.