# How to store an excel file in blob format in database and also with sha1 algorithm in python

Tags: python, database, excel, file, hashlib

I have an excel file in a particular directory and i need to store its contents in my database table file_logging

having columns as files_name,files_content,files_sha,files_date

```
FILE_NAME VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
FILES_CONTENT BLOB, 
FILES_DATE TIMESTAMP (6), 
FILES_SHA VARCHAR2(400 BYTE),
```

how could i perform it in a optimized manner

Comment: Dont' save files in a database. http://stackoverflow.com/a/41235395/267540