# How to retrieve and display images from mySQL database in jsp dropdown box as icon

Tags: mysql, jsp, servlets, model-view-controller

I am stuck :( Can you help me take a look !!!

So I want to create something like this:
[DropDown Box with icon and text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hrOn.png)

But I am stuck, I do not know exactly how to retrieve the image from database and display it in the dropdown box, but I tried something like this,

My JSP Page:

```
<%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>
<!DOCTYPE HTML><%@page language="java"contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>BudgetAdd</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<script>
function submitForm() {
    document.forms[0].action="BudgetAddServlet2";
    document.forms[0].method="POST";
    document.forms[0].submit();
}

</script>
</head>
<body>      
    <div id="BudgetMain">
    <div id="BudgetAddMain">
            <form action="/FinancialPlanner/BudgetAddServlet" method="post">
                <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                            <td class="BudgetAdd_tb">Month</td>
                            <td class="BudgetAdd_tb2"><select name="ddlMonth">
                                    <option value="Jan">Jan</option>
                                    <option value="Feb">Feb</option>
                                    <option value="Mar">Mar</option>
                                    <option value="Apr">Apr</option>
                                    <option value="May">May</option>
                                    <option value="Jun">Jun</option>
                                    <option value="Jul">Jul</option>
                                    <option value="Aug">Aug</option>
                                    <option value="Sep">Sep</option>
                                    <option value="Oct">Oct</option>
                                    <option value="Nov">Nov</option>
                                    <option value="Dec">Dec</option>
                            </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="BudgetAdd_tb">Budget Name</td>
                            <td class="BudgetAdd_tb2">
                            <select name="ddlBudgetName" id="ddlBudgetName">
                            <% ArrayList<String> categoryList = (ArrayList<String>)session.getAttribute("categoryList"); %>
                            <% for (String category:categoryList) { 
                            %>
                            <option value="<%=category %>"> <img src=''/> <%=category %></option>
                            <%} %>


                            </select></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td class="BudgetAdd_tb">Amount</td>
                            <td class="BudgetAdd_tb2">$ <input type="text" name="tbAmt" size="20" required></td>

                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td class="BudgetAdd_tb">Note</td>
                            <td class="BudgetAdd_tb2"><textarea rows="2" cols="100" name="tbNote"></textarea>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <input type="submit" id="confirm" name="btnSubmit" value="Add" class="confirmb" style="clear: right; height: 40px; background-color: #1c8942; vertical-align: middle; width: 120px; margin-top: 5px; float: right; text-align: center">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My servlet:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.sql.Blob;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import FinancialPlanner.DBConn.DBController;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class BudgetAddServlet2
 */
@WebServlet("/BudgetAddServlet2")
public class BudgetAddServlet2 extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public BudgetAddServlet2() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         InputStream sImage;

        try {
            DBController dbController = new DBController();
            dbController.getConnection();
            String dbQuery="select DISTINCT categoryName, categoryIcon FROM category" ;
//          dbQuery=dbQuery+ddlBudgetName +"')";
            System.out.println(dbQuery);
            ResultSet rs = dbController.readRequest(dbQuery);
            //ArrayList<String> categoryList;
            ArrayList<String> categoryList = new ArrayList<String>();
            //Iterate through the resultset
            while (rs.next())
        {

            String budgetCat = rs.getString(1);
            String budgetIco = rs.getString(2);
            categoryList.add(budgetCat);
            categoryList.add(budgetIco);


            }
            request.getSession().setAttribute("categoryList", categoryList);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        } 

        //Create an instance of the MovieBookingBean class
        request.getRequestDispatcher("BudgetAdd.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

My database:
[Database(I have saved the URL already)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mW0gy.png)

So, I am stuck at the JSP on how to retrieve the arraylist and to display it on my JSP page dropdownList.

Comment: Dont' save files in a database. http://stackoverflow.com/a/41235395/267540 if you had stored them properly in the file system, you wouldn't be having this problem

Comment: Thanks, for your reply!!! so now, I have change my categoryIcon as string in my database instead of blob. But I do not know how to retrieve to my textbox!, let me update my post first

Comment: what you should store in the database is the path to the file or it's url

Comment: I have already saved the URL but the problem now is that I do not know how to retrieve the Arraylist to my JSP select tag. Can you guide me on that! Thanks alot

Comment: You can do this by jstl forEach in jsp page

Comment: Thanks for the replies!! Don't understand how to use the jstl forEach even after i look at online exampes cause not really good at JSP T.T so for my case how to use thejstl>, <c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="5">
   NAME <c:out value="${i}"/><p>
</c:forEach>