# C#: file corrupted after downloading as byte array

Tags: c#, mysql, blob, file-format

I have a project in which I store documents as blobs in a MySQL database, and download them as byte arrays using C#:

```
public static byte[] GetFile(string fileName)
{
        conn.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = ...
        using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            reader.Read();
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                 return Util.ObjectToByteArray(reader["Content"]);
            }
          ...
}
```

...

```
public static byte[] ObjectToByteArray(object obj)
{
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        bf.Serialize(ms, obj);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

I upload the files like this:

```
byte[] newFile = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
```

and download like this:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(path + "\\" + selectedFileName, 
                   DocumentTable.GetFile(selectedFileName));
```

but when I download the files, they are corrupted and cannot be opened (for example Excel files, some other types can be opened). The extension of the downloaded file seems to be correct, but I am getting the message that "the file extension or file format are not valid".

Comment: Dont' save files in a database. http://stackoverflow.com/a/41235395/267540

Comment: Get a diff tool and then work in symmetrical stages - do the bare minimum part of your project that involves some kind of transformation, then run the bit that should undo that transformation, then compare the output to the input. Then build up and add complexity (upload/download, interaction with a DB, etc)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the GetStream() override of the data reader;

```
content = reader.GetStream(1);
```

and simply returning the stream object to your File writer.