# base64 enconded image send to android from python

Tags: android, python

I want to send base64 enconded image to android.
I'm sending an encoded string through a stream to Android from a Python server, and I get the following error:

> Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 228145336 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 215MB until OOM"

I've tried adding

```
android: largeHeap = "true"
android: allowBackup = "true"
```

to android `manifest.xml` and trying to increase the heap memory, but the same error still appears.

It seems to be a problem caused by the length of the base64 encoded image string being too long. Is there a way to reduce the length?
Or is there a way to have python display the images stored on your computer directly in url format?
Please help me.

Comment: Dont' save files in a database. http://stackoverflow.com/a/41235395/267540

Comment: `and I get the following error:`. Should we guess if that is with python or android?

Comment: 228GB seems awfully large for a single image, no matter how it's encoded.

Comment: PM 2Ring - Sorry to answer late. Does that mean you do not make sense that one image takes up so much capacity?

Comment: greenapps - this error apears in android.