# How to use bind_param to insert image into MySQL tables

Tags: php, mysql, insert, sql-insert

Given the following code for Inserting data into MySQL to prevent SQL Injection:

```
$img = "http://image-generated-online/";
$description = "An image";

$sql->prepare('INSERT INTO table(img, desc) VALUES (?,?)');
$sql->bind_param("attr-for-image, s", $img, $description);

$sql->execute();
```

Question: 
bind_param requires an attribute type. What is the attribute type for images?

Information that may be helplful:
data type is declared as `MEDIUMBLOB` in the SQL table

Comment: Dont' save files in a database. http://stackoverflow.com/a/41235395/267540

Comment: First, bind_param does not *require* an attribute. Second, why are you storing the images in the database, instead of just on the filesystem, with a link in the DB?

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie Because the images are generated on the fly through a link (gravatar). Would love to save the files but they are just links, unless there is a workaround?

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie when I removed the attribute types, I got the error bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables

Comment: Okay? So... Either you're saving the link, or you're saving the actual image. If you're saving the actual image in the database, then what's the difference saving it to file? Your statement doesn't make sense.

Comment: Found the reason: I separated the attributes with commas, when they are supposed to be in a single continuous string.

Comment: I can declare the variable as 'b' or blob

Comment: bind_param is for one value. You need to use two bind_params, or just use an array in the execute().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the column is a MEDIUMBLOB, you'll have to store the image as binary object, i.e., make a string from it.

It seems that your code did not yet download the image. After downloading the image, you'll have a string (binary object) that you can store in MySQL.

Comment: Ah yes... Thank you. I used file_get_contents to download the image and then inserted it into the database as a string.