# Undefined index php in inserting blob to database

Tags: php, mysql, indexing

I am trying to get image from user and save it in database, but it give this notice:

> Notice : undefine index :u_pic in ...

```
<input type="file" name ="u_pic" class="file" style="margin-top: 10px;margin-left:10%;margin-right: 10%;width: 80%">
$image=addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['u_pic']['temp_name']));
$insert = "insert into users (profilepicture) values ('$image' )";
```

Comment: did you added enctype='multipart/form-data' this in form ?

Comment: post your php and html code here ! yes it's not getting the index or name of your input for file

Comment: `$_FILES['u_pic']['temp_name']` is this proper exactly?

Comment: Dont' save files in a database. http://stackoverflow.com/a/41235395/267540

Comment: try to print_r($_FILES) to see if your form submitting files value that you want to server or not

Answer (score 1):

You can get image name using `$_FILES['u_pic']['name']`. You can get temp image name(location) using `$_FILES['u_pic']['tmp_name']`.

You should use `enctype='multipart/form-data` as a parameter in form tag. You should also use `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['u_pic']['tmp_name'],$_FILES['u_pic']['name'])` php function to move file from temporary location to server.

Try to use move_uploaded_file function to move the file and store `$_FILES['u_pic']['name']` as a filename in database table field.