# Insert CSV file into SQL Server (not import!)

Tags: python, sql-server, django, csv

I would like to store CSV files in SQL Server. I've created a table with column "myDoc" as varbinary(max). I generate the CSV's on a server using Python/Django. I would like to insert the actual CSV (not the path) as a BLOB object so that I can later retrieve the actual CSV file.

How do I do this? I haven't been able to make much headway with this documentation, as it mostly refers to .jpg's

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1904w6t(VS.80).aspx

Edit:
I wanted to add that I'm trying to avoid filestream. The CSVs are too small (5kb) and I don't need text search over them.

Comment: Dont' save files in a database. http://stackoverflow.com/a/41235395/267540

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want varbinary over varchar, but it will work either way

```
Insert Into YourTable (myDoc) 
Select doc = BulkColumn FROM  OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Working\SomeXMLFile.csv', SINGLE_BLOB) x
```