# Image not being Uploaded in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, html

This all started with me getting an unidentified index error: image. Then I put in the check before so I would not have to see the error again. However I know the images are not being uploaded. I have used legit images to test, and nothing is working. I have been struggling on this for hours. Please Help.

```
<html>
    <body>
      <form action="images-add.php" method="post" enctyp="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="image" />

        <input type="submit" name="sum" value="upload" />
      </form>
    </body>
</html>
<?php 
include('connection.php');

if(isset($_POST['image'])) {

if(empty($_FILES) || !isset($_FILES['image'])){
echo "Please Add an Image";
}else{
if(getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']) == FALSE){
            $image= addslashes($_FILES(['image']['tmp_name']));    
            $name= addslashes($_FILES(['image']['name']));
            $image= file_get_contents($image); 
            $image= base64_encode($image);
            saveimage($name, $image); 
   }
  }
 } 

function saveimage($name, $image){
      $con= mysql_connect("localhost", "root", ""); 
       mysql_select_db("hw2", $con);
        $qry= "insert into images (name, image) values ('$name', '$image')"; 
        $result= mysql_query($qry,$con); 
    if($result) {
     echo "<br/> Image Uploaded.";   
    }else{
        echo "Not Uploaded";     
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: as i read, could be the definition of field image in mysql

Comment: Dont' save files in a database. http://stackoverflow.com/a/41235395/267540 specially base64 encoded

Comment: correct enctyp to 'enctype' and use mysqli instead of mysql.

Comment: better upload images in the folder and save the path in the database. and you can show the image with href link to image path when necessary

Comment: Is this the real file, because the form action is `images-add.php`, not current file.

Comment: @PradeepKumarPrabaharan thanks I rewrote the code and am saving the image in a folder and the path to the DB. Works awesome now. Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change `enctyp` to `enctype` in your HTML form. 
Also update code 
From

```
$image= addslashes($_FILES(['image']['tmp_name']));
```

To

```
$image= addslashes($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
```

And
This line of code, From

```
$name= addslashes($_FILES(['image']['name']));
```

To

```
$name= addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
```

Complete code is given below...

```
<html>
    <body>
      <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="image" />

        <input type="submit" name="sum" value="upload" />
      </form>
    </body>
</html>
<?php 
include('connection.php');

if($_POST){
    if(empty($_FILES) || !isset($_FILES['image'])){
        echo "Please Add an Image";
    }else{
        if(getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])){

                $image= addslashes($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);    
                $name= addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
                $image= file_get_contents($image); 
                $image= base64_encode($image);
                saveimage($name, $image); 
        } 
    }
}

function saveimage($name, $image){
    $con= mysql_connect("localhost", "root", ""); 
    mysql_select_db("hw2", $con);
    $qry= "insert into images (name, image) values ('$name', '$image')"; 
    $result= mysql_query($qry,$con); 

    if($result) {
        echo "<br/> Image Uploaded.";   
    }else{
        echo "Not Uploaded";     
    }
}
?>
```

I hope this code will works for you.

Comment: I decided to save the path in the DB and the image in a folder. It was not working I rewrote the code from scratch based off this suggestion but did not work.

Comment: In you database table name "images" what is datatype of column "image"?

Comment: In your database, the table named "images" must have 'Blob' data type for the column named "image", after that, you will be able to save the image in it. 
if you don't have datatype as blob, then you can store the path of an image but not image itself.

Comment: it was saved that way.