# Node.js - Store and retrieve PDF to MySQL as BLOB using pdfkit

Tags: mysql, node.js, blob, pdfkit, node-pdfkit

I am having trouble storing a PDF content to MySQL as BLOB and retrieving it back from MySQL and stream it to front end using Node.JS.

I am able to save something to the DB (but not sure if I am saving the correct PDF content in the right manner). When I retrieve the pdf data, it does not open in PDF reader. I tried writing the retrieved data to a file and it also does not seem to work. Clear that either I am not storing the correct data to MySQL or I am not retrieving it in the correct way.

Could someone please help me out if you have come across similar scenario.

Code has been attached for your reference.

Many thanks.

```
var PDFDocument = require('pdfkit');
var doc = new PDFDocument;

var buffers = [];

doc.on('data', function(buff) {
    buffers.push(buff);
});

doc.on('end', function () {

    var queryToExec = "insert pdf_contents  SET ? ";
    var values = {
        id : 0,//Auto Incrementing column
        pdf: buffers.toString()
    };

    mysqlConnection.query(queryToExec, values, function(err, rows) {
        if(!err) {
            console.log("Stored to db successfully");
            var selQuery = "select pdf from pdf_contents order by id desc limit 1"
            mysqlConnection.query(selQuery, function(err_2, rows_2) {
                if(!err_2) {
                    var myPdfDoc = rows_2[0].pdf;
                    console.log("Retrieved successfully, but pdf could not be opened!");
                } else {
                    console.log("Error : ", err_2.toString());
                }
            });
        } else {
            console.log("Error : ", err.toString());
        }
    });
});

doc.addPage().text('Some text...', 100, 100);

doc.end();
```

Comment: Dont' save files in a database. http://stackoverflow.com/a/41235395/267540

Comment: But in my case, I run my node js application in 4 different servers load balanced by Nginx as the facing server. Each node js application server will be having access to a single MySQL server, however, the application servers will not have access to each other. So, in my case, I cannot store anything as a file because doing so might complicate things (like finding which file resides in which server)! Any solution to this type of scenario. Thanks for your response.