# image not showing after retriving it from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, html

Below is code for searching and displaying images based on username:

```
<?php
$s=0;
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "123456";
    $dbname = "photost";
    $conn=mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    $user_id=$_POST['user_id'];
    if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    $query="SELECT `id`,`image`, `file_name` FROM `images` WHERE `u_id`='$user_id'";
    $result =mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    $s=1;
}
?>
<body>
    <div style="width:100%;height:10%;">
    </div>
<div align=center>
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table style="width:40%">
    <tr>
    <th align="right">User Id:</th>
    <th> <input type='text' name='user_id'></th>
        <th align="left"> <input type="submit" name="submit"    ></th>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
<div style="width:80%;height:1000px;margin:auto;">
<?php
if($s==1){
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        $c=1;
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo "<div style='width:24%;float:left;margin-left:2px;margin-top:5px;'>";
            echo "<img style='height:250px;width:80%;margin:auto;' src=getImage.php?id='$row[id]' /><br>";
            echo $row["id"] .". ". $row["file_name"]."<br></div>";
            }
            }
}
 ?>
</div>


</body>
```

Below code is for fetching image from db based on image id:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
  $id = $_GET['id'];
  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "root";
  $password = "123456";
  $dbname = "photost";
  $conn=mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
  if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
  }
  header("content-type: image/jpeg");
  $query="SELECT `image` FROM `images` WHERE `id`='$id'";
  $result =mysqli_query($conn, $query);
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

  echo $row['image'];
}

?>
```

Tried Many Solution Nothing Worked.I'm able to display one image using header("content-type: image/jpeg") in main page.but while using it in getimage.php only image icon is displayed.as shown below:

[Screenshot (Images where userid=1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNp3J.png)

Plz Suggest me something.....

Comment: Dont' save files in a database. http://stackoverflow.com/a/41235395/267540

Comment: You are mixing APIs

Comment: What is the type of column `image` ? I think you are already saving the name of image file in `file_name` column. Then why don't you just use `echo "<img style='height:250px;width:80%;margin:auto; src='".$row["file_name"]."' />";` ?

Comment: yeah u r right i used that before

Comment: but thats also not working so i used another php file which will give images

Comment: Make sure the image files are stored in the same folder where your `*.php` file resides. Otherwise give the complete or relative path to the image file as the value of "src" attribute in `<img>` tag.

Comment: actually images are stored in db and for now im thinking to change storage from db to file server but for now i want to know why its not displaying.

Comment: it would be great if u can help in that thing

Comment: Can you just make this change in the first code `echo "<img style='height:250px;width:80%;margin:auto;' src='data:image/jpeg;base64,".base64_encode( $row['image'] )."'/><br>";` .

Comment: @ArjunSahani I have added an answer based on your comment. Feel free to accept it and up vote. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the following change in your first code:

`echo "<img style='height:250px;width:80%;margin:auto;' src='data:image/jpeg;base64,".base64_encode( $row['image'] )."'/><br>";`

Answer (score 0):

You need to prepend the relative path to the image directory to your retrieved filename (and make sure they are actually on your local disk! :))

```
$path     = "/your/path/to/images/";    
$filename = $row['image'];
$image    = $path.$filename;
```