# how to insert a file like file.txt or file.html to mysql

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql

how to insert the file in mysql to be then downloadable 
i'm using this code to display the file and insert it in mysql and i've chosen blob the type of the file in mysql. It works correctly but mysql let you download it in a binary format. This is my code

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <form  name="addform" action="addfile" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" onSubmit="return Check();">
        <h2>Adding a service</h2><br><br>
        <div class="row">
            <label>service name : </label><br>
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="service name" />
        </div><br>
        <div class="row">
            <label>file :</label><br>
            <input id="upload" type="file"   accept="text/html" size=30 name="fichier" placeholder="service">
        </div><br>
         <textarea class="form-control" rows=20 cols=10 id="ms_word_filtered_html"></textarea>
<br>
        <div class="row">
            <input class="btn" type='submit' value='Submit'>
            <input class="btn" type='reset' value='Reset'>
            <input class="btn" type='button' value='Back' onclick="javascript: location.href='/'">
            <br><br>
            <label class="msgerr">
                <%=msg %>
            </label>
        </div>
    </form>

<script>
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

    // use the 1st file from the list
    f = files[0];

    var reader = new FileReader();

    // Closure to capture the file information.
    reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
        return function(e) {

          jQuery( '#ms_word_filtered_html' ).val( e.target.result );
        };
      })(f);

      // Read in the image file as a data URL.
      reader.readAsText(f);
  }

  document.getElementById('upload').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
</script>
```

Comment: Dont' save files in a database. http://stackoverflow.com/a/41235395/267540

Comment: WTF?!! Databases (Relational/SQL) were built to store raw data not files! Why do you even want to store your entire HTML in DB? That just increases the load on your server and middleware and end user will have to wait longer than he would otherwise, not to mention the troubles of encoding/decoding characters. Moreover, you need a technology(like PHP, .NET, Java) that can use an MySQL driver to connect to the database to store/retrieve data, you don't mention what technology you plan to use!

Comment: I need to create a library in which i gonna upload some files to be then downloadable by the user. So have you another solution?