# Encoding data to blob file

Tags: mysql, pymysql

I'm working with blob files in a mysql database, and there is some new data that I'd like to encode to these blob files. The problem is, this new data, has to be put in at specific places in the blob file. 
The structure of my blob files are:

Old blob : 4 byte id 2 byte ref , 4 byte id 2 byte ref , 4 byte id 2 byte ref , ...

Now I have a new integer number that I'd like to encode into this file called link, also 2 byte long. So basically I want the new blob file to be like:

New blob : 4 byte id 2 byte ref 2 byte link , 4 byt id 2 byte ref 2 byte link , ...

How can this be done?

I'm working with pymysql in python to correspond with the mysql database, but I'm open for almost anything to fix this.

Comment: Dont' save files in a database. http://stackoverflow.com/a/41235395/267540

Comment: I can't do anything about it :) the data has to be in mysql

Comment: You need to fetch the entire content from the blob field, manipulate the byte array to include the links within python, and then update the field's content with the new byte array.

Comment: This is what I was afraid off