# displaying MYSQL BLOB

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, blob

I am having trouble loading blon from mysql. I was able to insert the image in the table. Whenever I save a blob I am getting [BLOB - 82.6 KiB] values which I think is correct. However, when I am trying to display it I am getting special charaters instead of an image. (����JFIF``���E)

Just for reference here is my connection string

```
$db = new PDO( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=wedding;charset=utf8', 'root','' );
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Here is my php code to save the image blob

```
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
$image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']));

}

if(!empty($image)){


try{
    require 'scripts/connection.php';    

    $updateprofile = "UPDATE users SET "
            . "photo = :photo "
            . "WHERE id = :id";
    $q = $db->prepare($updateprofile);
    $q->execute(array(
        ':photo'            => $image,
        ':id'               => $loggedid
        )); 
            echo "Uploaded successfully";
}catch(PDOException $exception){
        echo "Error: " . $exception->getMessage();


}
}else{
    echo "Please choose a file";
}
```

and here is my php code to retrieve it and display it

```
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT photo FROM users WHERE id=:loggedid ');
    $stmt ->execute(array(':loggedid'=> $loggedid));
    $stmt->bindColumn(1, $image, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
    $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND);
    header("Content-Type: image");
    echo $image;
```

table users are set to utf8_unicode_ci

Please help.. Thanks in advance

Comment: Dont' save files in a database. http://stackoverflow.com/a/41235395/267540

Comment: Why do you use `addslashes`? You are changing the data. Also, what e4c5 said.

Comment: I will appreciate if you can guide me in a better way to save it and display it.. I am still learning php

Comment: The best place to save files is on the __file__ system. only the path should go into the db