# Image uploading from angularjs 1.5 to grails 3 as byte[] and save it in postgresql as bytea

Tags: angularjs, postgresql, grails, grails-domain-class, grails-controller

I have searched for a solution in several days now. There are many examples where people is trying to upload a picture. 
I really need some help to come trough this. I have some code here and I hope someone could push me to through this.

I have added my code in this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/bv2kecdc/)

```js
//Angularjs controller :

self.createVaerksted = function(id, navn, by, nummer, billede) {
    var data = {};
    data.vaerkstedNavn = navn;
    data.byNavn = by;
    data.vaerkstedNummer = nummer;
    data.myImage = billede[0];

    vaerkstedService.createVaerksted(data)
      .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response)
      })

    // Angularjs service 
    var prefix = 'http://localhost:8080/api/';

    createVaerksted: function(data) {
      return $http.post(prefix + 'saveVaerksted', data)
    }
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Dont' save files in a database. http://stackoverflow.com/a/41235395/267540

Answer (score 0):

To upload a file (image, xls, etc) with AngularJS you can use a FormData.
For example, using Angular profile you can create a angular controller:

```
function UploadExcelController(domainServiceFactory, contextPath, $log, $state, $stateParams) {
var vm = this;

vm.contextPath = contextPath;
var UploadExcel = domainServiceFactory('/api/uploadExcel/:id', {id: '@id'}, {
    create: {
        method: "POST",
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
    }
});

vm.uploadExcel = function(data){
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("year", data["year"]);
    fd.append("excelFile", data["excelFile"][0]);
    $log.info(fd)
    UploadExcel.create({}, fd).$promise.then(function (res) {
        $state.go('dashboard');
    }).catch(function (err) {
        $log.info("error "+err);
        alert(""+err);
        throw err;
    });
}
```

Create a Grails Command:

```
class UploadExcelCommand implements Validateable {
MultipartFile excelFile
Integer year
static constraints = {
    year nullable: false
    excelFile validator: { val, obj ->
        if ( val == null ) {
            return false
        }
        if ( val.empty ) {
            return false
        }

        ['xlsx'].any { extension ->
            val.originalFilename?.toLowerCase()?.endsWith(extension)
        }
    }
}
```

and do the bussiness logic in the controller:

```
class UploadExcelController {

static responseFormats = ['json', 'xml']


def save(UploadExcelCommand cmd) {

    if( cmd.hasErrors() ) {
        render 404
        return
    }

    if( Excel.get(cmd.year) ){
        render 404
        return
    }

    println cmd.year
    println cmd.excelFile.inputStream

    render "OK"
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the post. One thing i don't understand is, why are you using id ->  /api/uploadExcel/:id', {id: '@id'},

Comment: And what is the content of domainServiceFactory ?

Comment: if you use the profile angular when you create the application it builds an agular service called domainServiceFactory who wraps $resource (https://github.com/grails-profiles/angularjs/blob/master/skeleton/grails-app/assets/javascripts/%40grails.codegen.defaultPackage.path%40/core/services/DomainServiceFactory.js)

Comment: My grails UploadExcelController can serve excel files in a rest way (get retrieve the excel with the id returned by save, and so on) but if you dont' need it you can omit :id

Comment: If it was useful for you can you vote as better answer ?