# How to embedd a PDF file from Database / PHP in HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql, blob, embed

I want to get a PDF File from a BLOB in my MySQL Database. The PHP for showing the PDF works fine:

```
<?php


$mysqli = new mysqli("192.168.1.11", "root", "password", "DB");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    die("Connection refused: " . $mysqli->connect_error);
}

try{
   $sql = "SELECT file FROM table WHERE id = 1";
   $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);        
   $row = mysqli_fetch_object($result);
   header('Content-type: application/pdf');

   echo $row->file;   

}catch(Exception $e){
    echo "caught exception: ", $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}

?>
```

Now i want to embed this PDF File into a HTML. I tried something like this:

```
<?php
$pdf = "MY_PDF_FILE.PDF";        ◄
echo <<<BLOCK
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
      <title>Embeded PDF</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <embed src="$pdf" type="application/pdf" height="25%" width="25%">
     </body>        ▲
  </html>
    BLOCK;
?>
```

I tried to save the `$row->file;` in the `$pdf` with `$pdf = $row->file;`. Always when i try to call the index.php of my website, it shows up, that the PDF File cannot be displayed and i only see the browsers PDF Viewer.

Can someone help me with this? :/

Comment: `$pdf` should be the URL of the first script that displays the PDF file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Slowness found when base 64 image select and encode from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41228496/slowness-found-when-base-64-image-select-and-encode-from-database)

Comment: Thanks barmar, that worked :)  Sorry for that easy question

Answer (score 0):

you can use an iframe element to show PDF.
You can load your base 64 encoded blob to data attribute of iframe.
Inside your data attribute you need to write: 'application/pdf;base64,' before base64 string.

```
<iframe data="data:application/pdf;base64,B64STRINGHERE" type="application/pdf" style="height:200px;width:60%"></iframe>
```

So you have to do something like:

```
<?php
    // Connection to DB + Retrive blob
    // We assume that your '$row->file' contains Blob data.
    // So encode '$row->file' to base 64
    $pdf = base64_encode($row->file); // BLOB TO BASE64
    echo <<<BLOCK
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
          <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
          <title>Embeded PDF</title>
        </head>
        <body>
          <iframe data="data:application/pdf;base64,$pdf" type="application/pdf" style="height:200px;width:60%"></iframe>
        </body>        
    </html>
    BLOCK;
?>
```