# Cannot encode object: pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo

I am trying to retrieve an audio file stored in `MongoDB` when above error is thrown.

The code is as follows:

```
elif json_data != None and 'retriever' in json_data:
    query_param = json_data['retriever']
    data = db.soundData
    x = data.find({'name': query_param})
    y = data.find({'data': x})
    return Response(y, mimetype='audio/mp3')
```

Under `name` I have the name of the file and under `data` is audio file itself. 
As I am new to `pymongo` can somebody point to where an error could be coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you [need not be saving your file itself in mongo](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41235395/267540) what you should be saving is the filename and the file itself is better off on the file system.

The error appears because, both x and y are indeed mongodb cursors rather than the data that you expect. You should be using [find_one](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one) instead.

> find_one(filter=None, *args, **kwargs) Get a single document from the
>   database.
>
> All arguments to find() are also valid arguments for find_one(),
>   although any limit argument will be ignored. Returns a single
>   document, or None if no matching document is found.

```
y = data.find_one({'data': x})
```

You can make your code a bit more concise with

```
y = data.find_one({'data': {'name': query_param}})
```